# String To Verify

Tags: c#

I am a C#.net developer.
I wanted to check if a source string contained all of the characters in the destination string.
ex:

```
Source String      : Test Check
Destination sting  : Check Test
```

Then wanted to check if each char(T,e,s,t,c,h,e,c,k) are present in the destination string?
The source string can contain numeric/alphanumeric/special characters to compare with destination string.

We can verify by loop through each & every character from the destination and match that to destination but that would takes time.

Is there any simple way to check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Except` + `Any`:

```
string sourceString ="Test Check";
string destString ="Check Test";
bool destStringContainsSource = !sourceString.Except(destString).Any();
```

or with [`HashSet.SetEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346516%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
HashSet<char> set = new HashSet<char>(sourceString);
destStringContainsSource = set.SetEquals(destString);
```

Both approaches don't take the number of characters into account.

The `Except`-approach does not even check if the destination-string contains more characters. It's just checking if the second string is a *subset* of the first. `SetEquals` is not quite the same.

You can use [`HashSet.IsSubsetOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358446(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the same behaviour:

```
HashSet<char> set = new HashSet<char>(sourceString);
bool sourceIsSubsetOfDest = set.IsSubsetOf(destString);
```

I would prefer the `HashSet` approaches since they are very efficient and most of all clear.

Answer (score 3):

You can use linq `All` method for this

```
string source = "Test Check";
string destination = "Check Test;

bool result = source.All(a => destination.Contains(a));
```

As @GrantWinney mentioned this solution won't take the number of letter occurences into consideration

Comment: You can use `source.All(destination.Contains);`